# Как изменить местоположение плашки с версиями на readthedocs?

Tags: python, документация

Пишу документацию к одному проекту, используя mkdocs под встроенной readthedocs темой. Не могу найти способ переместить плашку с версиями в левый нижний угол, в сайдбар. Может кто подскажет?

(То, что я пытаюсь сделать)
[image: То, что я пытаюсь сделать]

(Как это выглядит сейчас)
[image: Как это выглядит сейчас]